# javascript autoclick not working in php (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

There is a post type on my theme where a meta box is at the bottom of default body section. There is a "Add New" button at that metabox, when the button is being clicked a new section appears. I want the hidden section always being visible. I tried the javascript `click()` function so that the button becomes auto-clicked.

These are the theme original codes:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option-tree-social-links-add option-tree-ui-button button button-primary right hug-right" title="' . __( 'Add New', 'option-tree' ) . '">' . __( 'Add New', 'option-tree' ) . '</a> ';
```

I tried the following codes but its not working:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option-tree-list-item-add option-tree-ui-button button button-primary right hug-right" title="' . __( 'Add New', 'option-tree' ) . '">' . __( 'Add New', 'option-tree' ) . '</a> <script>document.getElementsByClassName("option-tree-list-item-add option-tree-ui-button button button-primary right hug-right")[0].click(); </script>';
```

Need help!

Comment: I would just remove the css that hides it so it is always visible.

Comment: You need to show the code that displays the section - and determine the following outcomes - is the section always there but just hidden with css (at which point you could write css to override the display state) or is it appended to the DOM (at which point you could write a function that recreates that action. The solution is not to necessarily autoclick the add button (and the code you are using for that above is incorrect) but to recreate the effect that the click achieves and write a function or css rule that allows that to happen on page load.

Comment: no the section is not hidden by css its hidden by php most probably, The followings are the original codes from theme php file. I have attached it in two comments

`if ( ! isset( $get_option ) )
  $get_option = '';
  
/* build list items */
echo '<ul class="option-tree-setting-wrap option-tree-sortable" data-name="' . esc_attr( $field_id ) . '" data-id="' . esc_attr( $post_id ) . '" data-get-option="' . esc_attr( $get_option ) . '" data-type="' . esc_attr( $type ) . '">';`

Comment: `if ( is_array( $field_value ) && ! empty( $field_value ) ) {
  foreach( $field_value as $key => $link ) {
 echo '<li class="ui-state-default list-list-item">';
   ot_social_links_view( $field_id, $key, $link, $post_id, $get_option, $field_settings, $type );
 echo '</li>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';

/* button */
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="option-tree-social-links-add option-tree-ui-button button button-primary right hug-right" title="' . __( 'Add New', 'option-tree' ) . '">' . __( 'Add New', 'option-tree' ) . '</a> ';`

Answer (score 0):

Best option for you to add custom meta box for post

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

But if you want to use js, then use this

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("option-tree-list-item-add option-tree-ui-button button button-primary right hug-right")[0].click();
});
```